# django-debug-toolbar middleware with django-social-auth context processor = InternalError

Tags: django, django-socialauth, django-debug-toolbar

the error is:

```
Exception Type: InternalError
Exception Value:    
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

TB:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
    except EmptyResultSet:
        if result_type == MULTI:
            return empty_iter()
        else:
            return
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
    if not result_type:
        return cursor
    if result_type == SINGLE:
        if self.query.ordering_aliases:
            return cursor.fetchone()[:-len(self.query.ordering_aliases)]
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
cursor  
<debug_toolbar.utils.tracking.db.NormalCursorWrapper object at 0x7f66692ce3d0>
self    
<django.db.models.sql.compiler.SQLCompiler object at 0x7f66692ce250>
params  
(u'/',)
result_type 
'multi'
sql 
'SELECT "promotions_pagepromotion"."id", "promotions_pagepromotion"."content_type_id", "promotions_pagepromotion"."object_id", "promotions_pagepromotion"."position", "promotions_pagepromotion"."display_order", "promotions_pagepromotion"."clicks", "promotions_pagepromotion"."date_created", "promotions_pagepromotion"."page_url", "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."name", "django_content_type"."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "promotions_pagepromotion" INNER JOIN "django_content_type" ON ("promotions_pagepromotion"."content_type_id" = "django_content_type"."id") WHERE "promotions_pagepromotion"."page_url" = %s  ORDER BY "promotions_pagepromotion"."display_order" ASC'
```

I did syncdb.

does anyone has a clue how to solve this?

is it related to debug-toolbar middleware order?

Comment: probably related to somewhere where you're fetching promotions.PagePromotions. Are you using raw queries?

Comment: No, promotions is not related to social-auth or debug-toolbar